# Why can't I vote to close a question with an open bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, bounty

The title of *[Are there any verses which say Vishnu is source of all avatars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32009)* looks fine but the body has several unrelated questions:

> - Since there are different Vishnus and such complexity in pancharatra, I want to know about root Vishnu from whom all other Vishnus and avatars emanate.
> - Which Vishnu is talked about when we say Vishnu's 10 avatars. Where does he stay?
> - What happens to this Vishnu when mortal world destroys?
> - What happens to chatur vyuha of mortal world?

And I can't vote to close it as 'too broad' because of an open bounty.

This looks like a loophole in the system to ask off-topic/too-broad questions and immediately start a bounty to prevent closure.

Comment: You can flag for moderator intervention and they can close.